# Read a file using Stream and keep track of the current index

Tags: java, android, lambda, java-8

I am reading a large file as such:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
    stream.skip(1).forEach(Main::parseLine);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

where parse line looks like this:

```
private static void parseLine(String line) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

what I would like to do is also keep track of the current line I am reading and have `parseLine` look like this instead:

```
private static void parseLine(String line, int idx) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collect the lines to a list then use `IntStream.range` or an explicit `for` loop to call your method passing the element along with the index:

```
List<String> result = stream.skip(1).collect(Collectors.toList());    
IntStream.range(0, result.size())
         .forEach(i -> parseLine(result.get(i), i));
```

Another option would be to use the [LineNumberReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) API.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom Consumer implementation, which keeps track of the index with the use of a counter variable:

```
stream.skip(1).forEach(new Consumer<String>(){
    private final long counter = 0L;

    @Override
    public void accept(String line){
        parseLine(line, counter++);
    }
});
```